# Which method is called when query-text changes in SearchView, while both Search suggestions and OnQueryTextListener interface are implemented?

Tags: android, loader, android-search

In the Android Documentation, in topic '***Adding Custom Suggestions***' for Search feature, it says that:

> When the user starts typing into the search dialog or search widget, the system queries your content provider for suggestions by calling `query()` each time a letter is typed.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html#CustomContentProvider

Also, in the documentation on **`SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`** interface (which is supposed to provide **Callbacks for changes to the query text**), the method `onQueryTextChange (String newText)`is

> Called when the query text is changed by the user.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html#onQueryTextChange%28java.lang.String%29

I am trying to implement `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`to make sure that the *Loader* is restarted in the call to `onQueryTextChange (String newText)` to deal with the "next" query because Android does not execute the query again when the query-text changes after first search(i.e. once a search has already been performed once).

**My question is**: If both **Custom Search suggestions** and **`SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`** interface have been implemented, then, which of these two methods `query()` (called by the Android system) and `onQueryTextChange (String newText)` (callback method) is called when the query text changes in SearchView widget?

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}
```

Note: Your activity should implement `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`

To answer to your question, `onQueryTextChange()` is called when the user type or delete a letter and `onQueryTextSubmit()` it's called when the user is pressing the done button on keyboard. You can easily check this by adding some `logcat`.

Comment: But, if the custom search suggestions are enabled in the search, then doesn't the Android system calls the query() method to *query* the ContentProvider each time a letter is typed?

Comment: What do you mean by Android query the ContentProvider ? You need to handle the search from your array or what do you have and replace the actual result with what do you have.

Comment: This is in context of 'Custom Search suggestions' for Search: _When the user starts typing into the search dialog or search widget, the system queries your content provider for suggestions by calling query() each time a letter is typed._

Comment: Please see this (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html#CustomContentProvider)

Comment: You could try this http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-adding-suggestions-to-search/